# How do I properly implement dropzone elements on my web app?

Tags: javascript, css, dropzone.js

I am trying to implement a Dropzone element to allow my user to easily drag and drop multiple files to upload into my web app. However, I don't really understand or know how to integrate the source code into my current solution. Can someone help me out on this?

Currently, I have a base.html to store all the frontend libraries/dependencies like bootstrap.min.css and jquery.min.js. Based on that understanding, i did a similar import for dropzone.js and dropzone.css. But I can't seemed to get it working.

"base.html" at root folder

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags-->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/basic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/dropzone.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/dropzone.js" /> 
    <script>
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        window.onload = function () {
            var dropzoneOptions = {
                dictDefaultMessage: 'Drop Here!',
                paramName: "file",
                maxFilesize: 2, // MB
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                init: function () {
                    this.on("success", function (file) {
                        console.log("success > " + file.name);
                    });
                }
            };
            var uploader = document.querySelector('#uploader');
            var newDropzone = new Dropzone(uploader, dropzoneOptions);
            console.log("Loaded");
        };
    </script>
    <!-- Font Awesome --> 
    <title>Market Data Terminal Analysis</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'includes/_navbar.html' %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {% block content %}{% endblock content%}
    </div>
</body>
```

I stored my dropzone.js and dropzone.css in root/includes/js and root/includes/css respectively.

Expecting a dropzone element on my page, but still not appearing.

Comment: see in console, is there any warning or error?